# Group custom page layouts in one group

Tags: content-type, page-layout, publishing-page

I have created page layouts based on custom content types.
At the time of creating page from that page layout I want to show my custom page layouts in one group.

[image]

As shown in above image, my page layouts are not shown in single group. Want to show them in single group.
 How can I achieve that?